# OleDb Update requires Insert Command?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I try to updata a single row, chosen by it ID. But what I got at best is an additional row instead of an updated one.

I made several attempts. Now I got a System.InvalidOperationException claiming that a valid InsertCommand is necessary for an update, if a DataRow listing will get a new row.

To me it is the same again: Why insert? I want to update.
Can anybody give me a hint?

This is my related code:

```
        string selectQuery = $"SELECT * FROM Records";
        string updateQuery = $"UPDATE Records SET AnyContent = @AnyContent  WHERE [ID] = @ID";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = null;
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;
        try
        {
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectQuery, ConnectionString);

            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = updateQuery;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@AnyContent", "066066");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 2);

            try
            {
                adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
                nbRowsChanged = adapter.Update(content);
            }
            finally
            {
                adapter?.Close();
                cmd?.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
            logText += "...Database Exception:\n\n" + e.Message + "\n\n";
            isSuccess = false;
        }

        if (0 < nbRowsChanged)
        {
            logText += ".... Success: Updated <" + nbRowsChanged.ToString() + "> rows.\n";
            isSuccess = true;
        }
```

<<< Update >>>

Originally I tried it with an OleDbCommandBuilder before. But CommandBuilder created an update command, which seems to me like an insert command.  This is why I tried it without CommandBuilder above. But inserting seems to follow me.

This is my old code, which is closer to where I want to get as it uses a DataTable instead of parameters:

```
        string selectQuery = $"SELECT * FROM Records WHERE [ID] = ?";

        OleDbConnection con = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = null;
        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = null;
        try
        {
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);

            adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectQuery, con);
            builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                nbRowsChanged = adapter.Update(content);
                logText += "....InsertCommand: " + builder.GetInsertCommand().CommandText + "\n"; // Just to debug
                logText += "....UpdateCommand: " + builder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText + "\n"; // Just to debug
            }
            finally
            {
                con?.Close();
                adapter?.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
            logText += "...Database Exception:\n\n" + e.Message + "\n\n";
            isSuccess = false;
        }

        if (0 < nbRowsChanged)
        {
            logText += ".... Success: Updated <" + nbRowsChanged.ToString() + "> rows.\n";
            isSuccess = true;
        }

        logText += tmpText ;
        logText += "...Database: Access disposed.\n";

        return isSuccess;
```

And this is the related trace:

```
        LogText:

       ...Database: Trying to update <1> number of rows in table <Records>
       ....InsertCommand: INSERT INTO Records (AnyContent) VALUES (?)
       ....UpdateCommand: UPDATE Records SET AnyContent = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND AnyContent IS NULL) OR (AnyContent = ?)))
       .... Success: Updated <1> rows.
       ...Database: Access disposed.
       NbRows Before: 5
       NbRows After: 6
```

Comment: When you call the Update method, [the DataAdapter analyzes the changes that have been made](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters) and executes the appropriate command (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE). When the DataAdapter encounters a change to a DataRow, it uses the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, or DeleteCommand to process the change.

Comment: Does it mean I always have to define insert, update and delete commands to be sure?

Comment: you are mixing OleDbCommand and OleDbDataAdapter. you need either one of them for DML commands

Comment: But why is it adding a row instead of updating? I use unit tests. DataTable has not been read from database, but created in a unit test. Might this be the reason why it is inserting instead of updating?

Comment: If you know before hand it will be and update, you could `adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead calling `adapter.Update()`.

Comment: @SonalBorkar: I unmixed it, using connection and adapter only. Defined all adapter-comands (select, update, insert, delete), too. I got no exception. But no further row has been added as well.

Comment: @bradbury9: I tried it as you said. Now I got exceptions or hints from the compiler again. This helps me. But it will need some time, until I got further results for you.

Comment: A Command has four different type queries 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Update 4) Insert.  The command builder (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) takes a Select Query and builds the other three automatically.  Then instead of creating you own Update Command Text you can use the Adapter Update method (adapter.Update).

Comment: @jdweng: I have tried this before. But command builder creates a command which seems not useful for me. This is why I try create a command by myself.

Comment: Did you check the command text for the Update from the CommandBuilder?  It may give a clue why your command isn't working.  ExecuteNonQuery() method returns a number which indicates the number of rows changed.  When the database has a primary key only one row can contain the primary key.  So when Update is used and there is no Primary key ExecuteNonQuery will return zero.  Then you need to use Insert.  When Insert is used and the Primary key exists then ExecuteNonQuery returns zero and you need to use Update.  Rather then deal with this issue I thought using Command Builder will handle issue.

Comment: See mdsn explanation of issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders.  I doesn't seem like CommandBuilder considers the Primary Keys so Update and Insert can fail like I explained in my previous comment.